# Prolog Comparing List

Tags: prolog

Write a predicate that shows whether or not list 1 ends with the same elements as list 2.

So something like

`endsWith([a,b,c,d,e], [c,d,e])` is true while

`endsWith([a,b,c,d,e], [c,e,d])` is false

Comment: Post some attempt you did please

Comment: Do you mean the first list ends with the whole second list, or that they share a common ending of at least one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With few lines of code you can sove your problem:

```
last([E],E):- !.
last([_|T],E):-
    last(T,E).

endsWith(L1,L2):-
    last(L1,E),
    last(L2,E).

?- endsWith([a,b,c,d,e], [c,d,e]).
true

?- endsWith([a,b,c,d,e], [c,e,d]).
false
```

First you find the last element of the first list and then check if it's equal to the last element of the second list. If you want to check if the first list ends with the second list, you can use `reverse/2` in this way:

```
compareLists(_,[]):- !.
compareLists([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    compareLists(T,T1).

endsWithAllElements(L1,L2):-
    reverse(L1,L1R),
    reverse(L2,L2R),
    compareLists(L1R,L2R).

?- endsWithAllElements([a,b,c,d,e], [c,e,d]).
false

?- endsWithAllElements([a,b,c,d,e], [c,d,e]).
true
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `endsWith([a|Xs],[b])` incorrectly fails

Comment: In addition, `last/2` is a predicate already provided by SWI and GNU Prolog. It's not generally a good idea to redefine a pre-defined predicate.

Comment: You could just use `append/3`: `same_end(L1, L2) :- append(_, [X|Xs], L1), append(_, [X|Xs], L2).`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure both lists end with a common sublist of at least one element:

```
same_end(L1, L2) :- append(_, [X|Xs], L1), append(_, [X|Xs], L2).
```

If you're really saying you want the first list to end in the second list:

```
same_end(L1, L2) :- append(_, L2, L1).
```